# Trying to use app on android device

Tags: ionic-framework

I got this error, when I try to login my app on my android device:

> D/chromium: Unknown chromium error: 0

What is it?

Here is my question on ionic forum
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/trying-to-use-app-on-android-device/46802

Comment: What's version of your android device. For older Android devices, there is a system provided browser that does not follow most web standards, CSS rendering, or even parsing and running JavaScript efficiently. Maybe you could use crosswalk webview and try again in order to verify whether old webview result in this error. Hope this will help you, regards!

Comment: Android 4.1.1
Crosswalk webview?